# Multilingual sites with different domains

Tags: php, wordpress, translation

I want to create a multilingual site and there are translators. I want to create 5 websites in different languages and the same contents and the top pages have different domains. There is a wordpress plugin of translation and flags are displayed on the toppages but if I click on a  flag I jump to a subdomain. But I want to jump to another toppage. If I click on a flag on a blog page, I want to jump to a blog page of a different site. How can I do that? Please help me.

I want to make 5 websites because if google find a website with a toppage written in Japanese, google thinks it's a Japanese website and the rank on Japanese google gets higher. Likewise, if google finds a site with a toppage written in French, the rank on French google gets higher.

Answer (score 2):

You could also only use sub-directories (google best practice) and easily create 1 website available in 5 languages with Weglot plugin https://weglot.com/wordpress-integration

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to do the following things...........
1. Install wordpress on 5 domain and connect to single database.and then use translation plugin.

Or, 
Buy and use https://wpml.org/. It gives you options to use different domains for every languages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own menu and not rely on the widget from the plugin you are using. The widget provided with your multilingual plugin wil have links like : www.example.com/fr & www.example.com/en . Or if you use WPML you have the option to link to different domains.

But i have to say that having different sites for all languages is not a good idea. Google will ignore websites with the same content. Google will think those sites are duplicates and your search results will suffer greatly. You have a setting in most multilingual plugins to auto detect your language based on your browser. This is far more superior imo than having a lot of different sites.